# Socket.io gets "bad handshake method" on Firefox, but not Chrome or Safari

Tags: socket.io, handshake

*[This is a duplicate of socket.io issue #2717 on Github. No answers there, I'd love to get some troubleshooting hints...]*

I have a test page (below) that creates a socket.io connection back to the server, then listens for and logs 'time' messages. It works as expected for recent Chrome and Safari on OSX 10.10.5. I'm using Socket.io 1.5.0 for all tests.

With Firefox 49.0.1, each POST request gets a response with `bad handshake method`. There is no `Socket.io connected...` message in the console, and no `time` messages arrive (see image). Other interesting info about the POST is:

```
- Params: EIO:3, t: LUuPeKr, transport:polling
- POST raw data: "1:1"
```

The test page connects back to a create-react-app app (0.6.1) that proxies the request to my own server on localhost:3001. As noted above, this page works as expected with Chrome and Safari.

What other info could I provide to debug this?

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>SOCKET.IO TEST PAGE</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Socket.io Test Page</h1>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('connect', function(data){
        console.log("Socket.io connected...");
    });

    socket.on('time', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

I was getting a bad handshake method error in chrome as well and fixed it by downgrading to socket.io 2.3.1 and the same for socketio-client

Comment: It's better to create a new issue with all the relevant details than to add onto a four year old question. What socket.io version(s) were you using previously? Did all browsers give the bad handshake error, or just some of them. Thanks.

Comment: worked great, actually it is 2.3.0 for the client, 2.3.1 for server.

Comment: I caved in and downgraded to 2.3.0.... still using vue-socket-io in the client. I'm thinking that vue-socket-io isn't compatible with the current version (3.0.0). I personally despise downgrading but if after 5 hours I will accept this solution. Thinking a newer version might work besides 2.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own post: Got a solution over on github. https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2717 tells about the fix to the socket.io code so that it always requests '*/*' instead of using Firefox's default.