# Socket.io with laravel POST 400 bad request

Tags: php, laravel, socket.io

I am using *redis* and *laravel-echo-server* for broadcasting.

When i init Echo in my **bootstrap.js** like:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.io = require('socket.io-client');

if (typeof io !== 'undefined') {
    window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'socket.io',
        host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
    })
}
```

I get error in console:

```
app.js:12063 POST http://app.blog:6001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NMmu7VC 400 (Bad Request)
```

When i click on it it shows:

```
{
   code: 2
   message: "Bad handshake method"
}
```

**laravel-echo-server.json**

```
{
"appKey": "base64:HfA91lrA3RDCklIxjodAFREue6lmhA1oslXYMVTceR8=",
"authHost": "app.blog",
"authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
"clients": [],
"database": "redis",
"databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {},
    "sqlite": {
        "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
},
"devMode": true,
"host": null,
"port": "6001",
"protocol": "http",
"socketio": {},
"secureOptions": 67108864,
"sslCertPath": "",
"sslKeyPath": "",
"sslCertChainPath": "",
"sslPassphrase": "",
"subscribers": {
    "http": true,
    "redis": true
},
"apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": false,
    "allowOrigin": "",
    "allowMethods": "",
    "allowHeaders": ""
}
```

}

Event broadcasting is working despite the error but i want to use broadcast notifications

Comment: can you please check which socket io and client version you using?

Comment: @EmtiazZahid socket.io-client is "^3.0.1"

Comment: check your browser console if it is a cors related issue or try to downgrade to version 2.3.0 for testing purpose

Comment: @EmtiazZahid yes downgrading to v2.3.0 works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure the exact reason but downgrading to [v2.3.0](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/releases/tag/2.3.0) the solution for that situation. found the relevant issue and the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034120/socket-io-gets-bad-handshake-method-on-firefox-but-not-chrome-or-safari?rq=1)

I think it's not related to laravel but socket io

You can add this issue to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues)

Comment: This has really helped me. Thanks! I still have an issue with `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400` on apache 2.4 - tried really lots of stuff so far. I don't suppose you have an idea for that as well?